# Countif Based On Another Column with filter In Excel

Tags: excel, vba, filter, countif

I am trying to perform a countif, based on criteria from another column with a filter.

Goal: Count the number of times MD in Column A chose "5" in column B, despite it having a filter.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You have a vba tag, can you please post your code so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=countifs(b:b,a:a,"MD",b:b,5)
```